# how to get record into a dropdown list using both an input field value and another dropdown list value

Tags: ajax

i have 2 tables(login and subject table respectively). the input field has the session user's id (from login table) while the 1st drop down list holds all the classes assigned to him/her (from subject table). how can i collect all the subjects assigned to each classes into a 2nd drop down list still from the subject table using ajax if possible. Note:(Subject table has classes,subjects, staffid). below is my code:

```
<td class="header">TEACHER ID:</td>
<td>
<label>
<input type="text" name="staffid" class="input_txt" id="teachID" value="
<?php echo $staffDetails->staffID; ?>"></label>
</td>
<td class="header">CLASS:</td>
<td>
    <select name="txtclassname" class="input_txt" id="class">
        <option value="">-- Select Class --</option>
<?php
 $staff = $staffDetails->staffID;
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT distinct className FROM subjects WHERE staffID = :sid");
 $stmt->execute(array("sid"=>$staff));
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
 <option value=""><?php echo $row['className']; ?></option>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 </select>
 </td>
<td class="header">SUBJECTS:</td>
    <td>
<!--I need all the subjects for a chosen class here-->
       <select name="txtclassname" class="input_txt" id="class">
          <option value="">--</option>
       </select>
    </td>
```

the modified javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('change', '#staffclass', function(){
    if($(this).val() !==""){
        $.ajax('get_staffSubjects.php?staffclass='+ $(this).val()).done(function(jsonOrHtml)){
            var JSON = JSON.parse(jsonOrHtml);
            var subjectSelect = $('#subject');
            subjectSelect.html('<option value="">--Select Subject--</option>');
            for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
                subjectSelect.append('<option value="">'+json[i]+'</option>');
            }
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

my server-side script (named:get_staffSubjects.php)

```
<?php
require_once 'myConn.php';
require_once 'session.php';
$db = getDB();

if(($_POST['staffclass']) & ($_POST['teachID']))
{
$staff = $_POST['teachID'];
$subs = $_POST['staffclass'];    
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE className=:staffclass AND staffID=:teachID");
$stmt->execute(array('id'=>$subs, 'teachID'=>$staff));
?>
<option value="">Select Subject:</option>
<?php
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>
<option value=""><?php echo $row['subName']; ?></option>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi & welcome to stackoverflow. I'll just assume you know what to do on the server side to get the subjects, and show you how to use jquery to get them via ajax.

```
<td class="header">TEACHER ID:</td>
<td>
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="staffid" class="input_txt" id="teachID" value="<?php echo $staffDetails->staffID; ?>">
    </label>
</td>
<td class="header">CLASS:</td>
<td>
    <select name="txtclassname" class="input_txt" id="class">
        <option value="">-- Select Class --</option>
 <?php
 $staff = $staffDetails->staffID;
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT distinct className FROM subjects WHERE staffID = :sid");
 $stmt->execute(array("sid"=>$staff));
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
     <option value=""><?php echo $row['className']; ?></option>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
     </select>
</td>
<td class="header">SUBJECTS:</td>
<td>
<!--Notice that I've changed the name and id of this drop-down, as I expect you need those to be unique -->
   <select name="txtsubject" class="input_txt" id="subject">
      <option value="">--Select Subject--</option>
   </select>
</td>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //I'm using jquery, which is a quick solution
    //NB: I don't like that the id='class', better use some other name
$(document).ready(function(){ // this ensure the code below happens after page is fully loaded
    $(document).on('change', '#class', function(){
        if($(this).val()!==""){
             $.ajax('get_staffSubjects.php?staffclass='+ $(this).val()).done(function(html){

                var subjectSelect = $('#subject');
                //since html is constructed on the server side, we'll just append the response to the drop-down
                subjectSelect.html(html);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. i will get back to you as soon as am done with your code.

Comment: Further reading for jQuery ajax can be found here: [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: i have tried it but the subject drop downlist isn't changing at all

Comment: can I see your server-side script? hope you know `your_php_script.php` is meant to be replaced by your actual script for getting the data?

Comment: please can you check this code to see my errors please: yes i did changed it

Comment: This is not legible. I suggest you edit your question and add proper formatting to the code.

Comment: ok, I'm going to edit my answer to match your server side output

Comment: please in the script ($(document).on('change', '#class') what is the 'change' there for. am still trying to make it work but hasn't worked yet. thanks

Comment: Sorry, that code should actually be wrapped in a document ready event. I'll edit my answer. You can read about [jQuery.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) if you want

Comment: can you check your browser for javascript errors? At least even check the network tab if the request is reaching your php script

Comment: Hi. Just want to say thank you so much. i just got it fixed 2day. am sorry i av been away from my system all these days to give u feedback. thanks am grateful

Comment: Thanks i av done dat. am sorry about that. Thanks alot

Comment: Please i have a serious challenge with an ajax code please can u be of help

Comment: What's the challenge? You may be better off posting a question, so the entire SO community can contribute.